# How to generate one row per week when specifying a month in the WHERE clause PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database (psql) which is supposed to work as a Library Management System. I have a table called `borrowed` which contains some information about each borrowing of books. Each book has a `borrowdate` column, a date value specifying when the book was borrowed from the Library. Each book also has a `returndate` column, which tells us when the book was returned. If it hasn't been returned, the value of `returndate` will be `null`.

I'm now trying to write a query that presents a table that shows a monthly report for the number of books borrowed/returned for each week (for example week 1-4). I've managed to write a query that shows a table of the number of books borrowed, returned, and not returned (missing) for a specified time interval. Time interval is provided in the `WHERE` clause.

How can I split this time interval up into 4 equally sized parts so that I'll get one row for each part? Essentially, I want to get one row per week in a month. See my query below!

```sql
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(borrowid)) AS week,
  COUNT(borrowid) AS borrowedbooks, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN returndate IS  NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS returnedbooks, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN returndate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 1 END) - 
    SUM(CASE WHEN returndate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missingbooks 
FROM borrowed 
WHERE borrowdate >= '20190901' 
AND borrowdate <= '20190930'
;
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results woudl really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is aggregation, but by what?  You can calculate the date as a week and `group by` that calculation:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(borrowdate, 'IYYY-IW') AS week, 
       COUNT(borrowid) AS borrowedbooks,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE returndate IS NOT NULL) AS returnedbooks, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE returndate IS NULL) AS missingbooks
FROM borrowed
WHERE borrowdate >= '20190901' AND borrowdate <= '20190930'
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

Note that this uses `TO_CHAR()` to generate a standard definition for "week".

Note that I changed the conditional aggregation logic.  Postgres supports the standard `FILTER` clause, so I've used that.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer!! This is very close to what I wanted! Any idea of how to insert another column which enumerates the rows? (First row has a 1, second row has a 2 etc). Thanks a lot again for your quick answer, and also for teaching me how to use the FILTER clause!

Comment: @KTHKarl . . . You can add your `row_number()` expression back in.